# Why is my Linked List not getting printed?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list taking user input and print the same, however, my linked list is getting created but I am unable to `print` it. Here is the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Node
{
    int data;
    Node next;
}
public class LinkedList
{
    public static void create(Node start)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Node a = new Node();
        System.out.println("Enter Details:");
        a.data = sc.nextInt();
        a.next = null;
        start = a;
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?");
        char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
        while(ch!='n')
        {
            Node b = new Node();
            System.out.println("Enter Details:");
            b.data=sc.nextInt();
            b.next = null;
            a.next = b;
            a=b;
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?");
            ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    public static void display(Node start)
    {
        Node temp = start;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node start=null;
        create(start);
        display(start);
    }
}
```

I am unable to find the problem please help me find how to `print` my linked list.

Comment: YOu instantiate the start as null. During debugging, i found that because it is null, the display method does not run. because while loop is false

Comment: I believe the issue you are facing is due to the property of java which passes by value. You are not replacing the start with a. Although it looks like u assign start to be a, you are only dealing with a local reference. It does not return back to original start node.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73021/12181863 `You can assign a pointer, pass the pointer to a method, follow the pointer in the method and change the data that was pointed to. However, the caller will not see any changes you make to where that pointer points.`

Answer (score 1):

The diagnosis is really very simple:

```
    Node start=null;
    create(start);
    display(start);
```

You are calling the `display` method on `null`.

The problem is that your `create` method does not ... and cannot ... change the value of the `start` variable.  To make this work, you are going to have to change `create` so that it builds and returns a list, and then *assign the result* of the `create()` call to `start`.

Note that you can (and should) get rid of the parameter to `create` as its value is effectively never used in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The working code is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Node {
    int data;
     Node next;
    }

public class LinkedList {

private static Node start;

public Node create(Node start) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node node = new Node();
    System.out.println("Enter Details:");
    node.data = sc.nextInt();
    node.next = null;
    start = node;
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?");
    char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
    while (ch != 'n') {
        Node b = new Node();
        System.out.println("Enter Details:");
        b.data = sc.nextInt();
        b.next = null;
        node.next = b;
        node = b;
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?");
        ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
    }
    sc.close();
    return node;
}

public void display(Node start) {
    Node temp = start;
    while (temp != null) {
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp = temp.next;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
    Node node = linkedList.create(start);
    linkedList.display(node);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `start` node to the `create` method won't make it the head node of the list. It still would be `null`.
There are many ways to achieve what you want, like:

1. Display the list inside the `create` method itself as:

```java
while(ch!='n')
{ /* ... */ }
display(start);
sc.close();
```

2. Change the method return type so that it returns the `start` (head) node which can be used to traverse the list:

```
public static Node create(Node start)
{
    // Creating list
    return start;
}
```

Method call:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Node start=null;
    start=create(start);
    display(start);
}
```